# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of inpu

Tags: node.js, вконтакте, бот

````
console.log('-------------------------------')
console.log('  vk-bot запущен.')
console.log('  Написан: ����')
console.log('  https://vk.com/����')
console.log('-------------------------------')
console.log('')
const { VK } = require('vk-io');
const { HearManager } = require('@vk-io/hear')
const vk = new VK({
    token: "ff9ac4f39527d7c856198e454aa3b09a5fb1826fe8c3f9ec0c8ad955e7a1b57efee3b75ae4ff3445d7441"
})
let config = require('./database/config.json');
const commands = [];
let developer = 582059218;
let accounts = require('./database/accounts.json');
setInterval(async () => { await saveAll(); }, 500);
const utils = {
    pick: (array) => { return array[utils.random(array.length - 1)]; },
    random: (x, y) => { return y ? Math.round(Math.random() * (y - x)) + x : Math.round(Math.random() * x); }
}
const keyboard = (object) => {
    return {
        keyboard:JSON.stringify({
            one_time: false,
            buttons: object
        })
    }
}
async function saveAccounts() { require('fs').writeFileSync('./database/accounts.json', JSON.stringify(accounts, null, '\t')); return true; }
async function saveAll() { require('fs').writeFileSync('./database/accounts.json', JSON.stringify(accounts, null, '\t')); return true; }
vk.updates.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(Number(message.senderId) <= 0) return;
    if(/\[club204049539\|(.*)\]/i.test(message.text)) message.text = message.text.replace(/\[club204049539\|(.*)\]/ig, '').trim();
    if(message.isChat) return;
    let res = await vkc.api.getMyBalance();
    console.log(Number(res))
    if(!accounts.find(x=> x.id === message.senderId))
    {
        const [user_info] = await vk.api.users.get({ user_id: message.senderId });
        const date = new Date();
        accounts.push({
            id: message.senderId,
            uid: accounts.length,
            name: user_info.first_name
        });
        saveAccounts();
        return message.send(`Вы зарегестрированны!`, keyboard(
        [[{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{}",
                "label": " Удвоить Деньги "
            },
            "color": "positive"
        }],
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{}",
                "label": " Инфо "
            },
            "color": "negative"
        }]
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{}",
                "label": "Вывод"
            },
            "color": "negative"
        }]]));
 
const cmd = {
    hear: (p, f) => {
        commands.push([p, f]);
    }
}
cmd.hear(/^(?: Удвоить Деньги )$/i, async(message, bot) =>{
    return bot(` Вам нужно будет перейти и оплатить любую по ссылке`)
    return bot(`Незабуть указать айди: ${message.senderId} в коментарии`);
});

    
cmd.hear(/^(?: Инфо )$/i, async(message, bot) =>{
    return bot(`Инфо`);
});

cmd.hear(/^(?:Начать)$/i, async(message, bot) =>{
    return bot(`Вы зарегестрированны!`);
});

vk.updates.startPolling```
````

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос. На какой платформе запускается, когда получается ошибка? при запуске, при получении сообщения?

Comment: А что именно сделать?

Comment: Если не сложно можешь скинуть рабочий код